# Remove css class from element when reCAPTCHA is successful - Nextjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm attempting to remove a css class `btn-disabled` from the input button element when someone verifies their entry to the form.

I currently created a function called `enableForm` to remove the CSS class `btn-disabled` when reCAPTCHA is verified.

At the moment my CSS class does not get removed which doesn't allow the form to submit. My console.log `yes` is appearing so the function is being called but I am not able to remove the CSS class. This method was working previously using regular javascript now I'm attempting to do the same on nextjs. How can I remove my CSS class on the success of reCAPTCHA?

Here is my code snippet:

```
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

const TopForm = () => {

const enableForm = function () {
        console.log('yes')
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").classList.remove = "btn-disabled";
    };

return (
 <div> 
 <input
                    id="first_name"
                    maxlength="40"
                    name="first_name"
                    size="20"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="First Name*"
                    className="field"
                />
                <br />

                <input
                    id="last_name"
                    maxlength="80"
                    name="last_name"
                    size="20"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Last Name*"
                    className="field"
                />
          <ReCAPTCHA 
                sitekey="XXXXXX"
                onChange={enableForm}
                />
<input
                    id="btnSubmit"
                    type="submit"
                    name="submit"
                    className="btn-disabled btn-alternative width-inherit margin-left-0 "
                />

</div>
)

}
```

`btn-disabled` has CSS properties of :

```
.btn-disabled {cursor:not-allowed;opacity:0.5;text-decoration:none;pointer-events: none;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage in a better way the classes based on the value of your state

```
        import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

const TopForm = () => {

const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);


const enableForm = function () {
        console.log('yes')
        setIsActive(true)
    };

return (
 <div> 
 <input
                    id="first_name"
                    maxlength="40"
                    name="first_name"
                    size="20"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="First Name*"
                    className="field"
                />
                <br />

                <input
                    id="last_name"
                    maxlength="80"
                    name="last_name"
                    size="20"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Last Name*"
                    className="field"
                />
          <ReCAPTCHA 
                sitekey="XXXXXX"
                onChange={enableForm}
                />
<input
                    id="btnSubmit"
                    type="submit"
                    name="submit"
                    className={`constant1 ${isActive ? "active" : ""} btn-alternative width-inherit margin-left-0`}
                />

</div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you accidentally have made the mistake of assigning a function rather than calling it.

Here is what it should be:

```js
const enableForm = function () {
        console.log('yes')
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").classList.remove("btn-disabled");
    };
```

It should work now.

Comment: could you please elaborate? This resolve the issue but your code looks exactly like what I had in my eyes

Comment: I see it shouldn't have been = "btn-disabled";

Comment: please note that this is an anti pattern to react